# MySQL difficult SELECT

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I speak a little English. It's ok:

```
SELECT `post`.`people`, `link`.`var`, 
  `post`.`date`, `private__tz`.`code` 
FROM `link` 
INNER JOIN `post` ON 
  `link`.`post_id` = `post`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `private__tz` ON `post`.`date_tz` = `private__tz`.`id` 
WHERE `link`.`category_id` = '" . $category [ 'id' ] . "' 
AND `link`.`state` IS NULL 
GROUP BY `link`.`var` 
ORDER BY `post`.`date` DESC
```

I would like `me`, but it's not work:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(
    SELECT * FROM `action` 
      WHERE `action`.`var`=`link`.`var`
  ))>0, 'yes', 'no') AS `me`, ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Based on where your `--` comment characters are, I think you're missing some line breaks that would the question easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry but you have to explain better and ask a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (and that's a little difficult in itself), you want to add a new column (`me`) to your existing query?  If so, you need to `outer join` to the table `private__het__action`.  Then you can add your `IF` statement in.

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT `private__het__post`.`people`, `private__het__link`.`var`, `private__het__post`.`date`, `private__tz`.`code`,
   if (COUNT(`private__het__action`.`var`) > 0, 'yes', 'no') `me`
FROM `private__het__link` 
   INNER JOIN `private__het__post` ON `private__het__link`.`post_id` = `private__het__post`.`id` 
   INNER JOIN `private__tz` ON `private__het__post`.`date_tz` = `private__tz`.`id` 
   LEFT JOIN `private__het__action` ON `private__het__action`.`var`=`private__het__link`.`var`
WHERE ...
```

BTW, your life would be easier if you'd use table aliases.